# What time is considered day and night?

Tags: the-witcher-3

In *Witcher 3*, certain Quests and Actions can only be performed during the Day or Night. What hour does each start at? I thought that 6 am and onwards would be Day, but I notice that at least 5 am and possibly earlier is also considered Daytime.

Comment: How did you notice that 5 am already counts as daytime?

Comment: I have an ability that heals me when it's day time, and it was between 5 am and 6 am and I was already being healed. If I pay closer attention I'm sure I can eventually figure out the times, but I thought it was common knowledge perhaps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Daytime is considered the time between 4:00 a.m. and 9:59 p.m. and so night
time is between 10:00 p.m. and 3:59 a.m.

More precisely, the time is divided into four categories:

**Morning** between 4:00 a.m. and 9:59 a.m.
[image: Morning]

**Noon** between 10:00 a.m. and 3:59 p.m.
[image: Noon]

**Evening** between 4:00 p.m. and 9:59 p.m.
[image: Evening]

**Night** between 10:00 p.m. and 3:59 a.m.
[image: Night]

Morning, noon and evening all count as daytime, since the ability "Sun and Stars" regenerates Geralt's health during that time.

Comment: Thanks! Would you also happen to know what time shops open?

Answer (score 0):

All I know that when they say "meet me at sundown" or something along those lines then it means after 6pm.